# HealthKit background delivery running many times in a minute

Tags: ios, iphone, healthkit

I've registered for background delivery of four types of HealthKit data in my delegate's `didFinishLaunching` method. The data types are steps, sleep, workouts, and `energyConsumed`.

I've noticed my observer queries for these data types are being called by HealthKit/iOS many, many times a second in some cases. Here's an example from some device logs of the sleep observer query being called:

> 2017/03/27 07:21:58:821  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:58:894  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:58:936  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:58:973  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:58:993  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:000  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:024  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:130  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:145  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:156  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:169  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:309  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:328  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:346  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:404  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:480  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:499  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:520  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:547  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:561  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:571  Delegate - steps observer query received new data
>
> 2017/03/27 07:21:59:583  Delegate - steps observer query received new data

Here's the code in my app delegate where this log is created:

```
- (void)setUpStepsObserverQuery {

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

HKSampleType *sampleType = [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount];
HKObserverQuery *query = [[HKObserverQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:sampleType predicate:nil updateHandler:^(HKObserverQuery *query, HKObserverQueryCompletionHandler completionHandler, NSError *error) {

    if (completionHandler) {
        completionHandler();
    }
           
    if (error) {
        DDLogDebug(@"App Delegate - An error occured while setting up the stepCount observer: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    
    } else {
        DDLogDebug(@"Delegate - steps observer query received new data");
        
        weakSelf.activityTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            [weakSelf endBackgroundTask:weakSelf.activityTask];
        }];

// At this point I run an anchor query to check if there really is new data, and if there is I go ahead and send the new HealthKit data to our server.

    }];

    [_healthStore executeQuery:query]; // _healthStore is a shared instance of HKHealthStore I created earlier
}
```

This is how I enable background delivery for steps data. I call this method in `didFinishLaunching` and it calls the method I've shared a snippet of above, `setUpStepsObserverQuery`

```
if ([defaults boolForKey:HK_ACTIVITY_SYNC]) {
    [self setUpStepsObserverQuery];
    [_healthStore enableBackgroundDeliveryForType:[HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount]
                                        frequency:HKUpdateFrequencyImmediate
                                   withCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                       DDLogDebug(@"Delegate - enabled step count background updates");
                                   }];
```

Any ideas on why HealthKit would be calling my observer queries so many times in the same minute?

Answer (score 3):

This is because every time your observe query gets called, your `didFinishLaunching` function is also called, and `enableBackgroundDeliveryForType` gets also called and each time it's enabled, the query is being performed.

you have to check if background delivery is enabled, don't enable it again!

Comment: I have just found this thread and am having a similar issue. How do i check if background delivery is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug rather than expected behavior, so you should file a radar with [Apple](https://bugreporter.apple.com).

You could also try specifying less frequent `HKUpdateFrequency` such as `HKUpdate​Frequency​Hourly`. As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614175-enablebackgrounddeliveryfortype) for `HKHealthStore`, the system is actually intended to have a minimum frequency of hourly for high volume sample types such as steps and active energy.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll try to reproduce it with a small project and file a radar. Perhaps I read the docs wrong, but I thought they were saying even if I ask for steps (for instance) immediately, I'll never be notified more than once per hour, regardless. In other cases I do want to be notified immediately, because for something like sleep, I can't rely on being notified soon enough after the user wakes up in the morning unless I ask for the data to be sent to me immediately.

Comment: @BelleB.Cooper Most helpful thing to gather for a Radar about this would be a sysdiagnose (http://adcdownload.apple.com/iOS/iOS_Logs/sysdiagnose_Logging_Instructions.pdf) from a device reproducing the issue. I think you understand the docs correctly, but I'm just suggesting a workaround you could try to avoid the problem with steps for now.